# What's the structure of this word / sentence? 搬进、走出、跑回

Tags: vocabulary, sentence-structure, phrase

What's the structure of these words? 搬进、走出、跑回......

I think both 搬 and 进 can be verbs but when used together, it means 'move in'.

What's the relationship between the two characters in phrases like those?

For example, only 搬 is the verb in the sentence ‘我们搬进了一幢楼房’，but not ‘进’，what is the role of ‘进’ in the sentence?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The “进” part is called [directional complement](https://app.ninchanese.com/stage/grammar-lesson/91/99).

> Rather simply, as we do in English, you can add a directional word to the verb, to describe where the verb is going. The most common words to indicate a direction are:
>
> - 上, up and 下, down <== notice how they kind of look like arrows?
> - 进, in and 出, out
> - 过, to cross over
> - 起, up
> - 回 to come back.
> - 到 (to arrive) to

So, “搬进” is “move in/into”, “走出” is “walk out (of)”, “跑回” is “run back to”.

Answer (score 3):

Quote:- "...only 搬 is the verb in the sentence ‘我们搬进了一幢楼房’，but not ‘进’，what is the role of ‘进’ in the sentence?

搬进, (move in), is a "compound verb" -- i.e. a verb that is made up of multiple words.

In English, you have "I *believe in* you"; "His car *swerved and tumbled* *over*", "You need to *work on* your Chinese", :)

So, without the 进, your sentence would read 我们搬了一幢楼房, meaning, "We moved the building"

Answer (score 0):

You could also say:

我们搬到了一幢楼房里面。or 我们搬进一幢楼房里面。

Seems somehow more complete with 到 --- 里面

Wayne is completely correct, without 到 or 进 you'd be moving the building!

我们搬了一幢楼房！

Superwoman EmmaXL!

Answer (score 0):

进 can be both verb or directional complement. It can be a verb if it's used alone. for example, if we say "我们进了一幢楼房", it means "we walked into the building".

But when it's used right after another verb, it's a directional complement, and it's used to clarify the direction of the verb in front of it. In the sentence "we move in the building", 搬 corresponds to "move", and "进" means "in".

Please let me know if you have further questions~

Answer (score 0):

搬进 => 搬出
走出 => 走回
跑回 => 跑出

In this words,进,出 and 回 represent from where to where.
搬,走 and 跑 represent the action.